# Create a burndown chart for a single Team Member in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, burndowncharts

I love Azure DevOps and burndown charts even more, I really do.

So much that I am trying to substitute the legacy Excel Spreadsheet with DevOps.

While the default burndown chart takes into account all the members of a team, I'd need to get one **for each of the team members**.

Is there a way to do it ? And if there is more than one, which is the best ?

Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops#choose-the-teams-and-work-items-to-chart) it could come to my mind to create a new team for each team member... but it sounds stupid. Anyone had the same requirement before ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is currently no effective solution to this issue. Burndown are meant for teams, and the focus of team members have to be to make the team burn down reach it's targets.

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT, even if the main focus is on the team, and I agree on that, nonetheless I'd like to know which contribute has been given from each of the team members. And I think I am not the only one, seeing the request ! Thanks anyway, I am still positively hoping there is a way to implement it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no out of the box way to see burndown chart of individual team member. [Users have requested](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365402/have-a-burndown-chart-per-team-member.html) this feature and is currently under review.

Comment: Thanks for providing this info Shridhar, I immediately put a +1 on the request ! I was hoping in some DIY solution to implement it... let's see if someone already figured it out !

Comment: Sadly it's not a solution, but the information you gave me was quite valuable

Comment: Yeah, I'll research more if I can get you a solution.

Comment: Has this changed since this was answered?  This question was the top Google result.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box.  However if you have Power BI there is a [plug in for Azure Dev Ops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops) that is currently in beta.

This essentially will give access to the raw data exposed via APIs in Azure Dev Ops.

Once connected multiple burndown charts could be created or have a static filter for each one.  Or alternatively create page filters so you could quickly filter by team member.  The trick here will be to get the data model correct for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is interesting... we don’t use power bi yet but it makes sense, you have a more powerful charting tool to which you delegate the burndown... Were you able to implement this or it’s a theoretical solution @DreadedFrost ?

Comment: Power BI is free to use until you get to the sharing and distributing of data and dashboards.  This was theoretical so I went ahead and connected to a few projects to see what all you can do.  It turns out from what I can see the 'Effort' field in DevOps does not come across so a "true burndown" does not seem to be possible.  However if doing a burndown in terms of pure number of tasks this is one potentially solution as the chart would use the count of work items assigned per user.

Comment: Thanks @DreadedFrost, yes I managed too to graph, directly in DevOps, the "burndown" of active tasks assigned to each of the team member, but that lacks the dimension of the effort, which is the defining feature that drove me to move to DevOps fromTrello that I was using before.Thanks again for investigating !